# Given a total recursive function, can you always compute its fixed-point?

Tags: computability

We know from Kleene's recursion theorem that if $f$ is total recursive, there must be an integer $n$ for which $\varphi_n=\varphi_{f(n)}$. My question is: for every $f$ total recursive, is there a computable (total) procedure that computes such a point?

ie: $\exists g.\forall f.\varphi_{g(n)}=\varphi_{f(g(n))}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proof of the recursion theorem is *constructive*: it gives you an algorithm to compute $n$ from $f$. See for example [these notes](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/cf6e/3e9ea50601664a768b9d0f90891e2559dc24.pdf) of Rebecca Weber.